# Can I put a table view within a page view controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I wanted to know I could put a table view inside a page view controller. Basically what I'm trying to do is I have a screen where I want to display a question with a list of answers that has radio buttons. And on click of next button I should move to the next question and on click of previous button I should go back to the previous question. Also I want to store which answer is selected for the respective question.

Can I do it by putting a table view a within a Page View Controller? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can put whatever you want on these pages.

Comment: @meaning-matters how to get the previously selected answer when I click on previous button?

Comment: Don't you want to save the answers somewhere central for final processing?

Comment: Yes on click of next button i will take the id from the selected row and pushing it to an array.

Comment: Well, then you can use the page index to find the answer in that array. Good luck, now first try something yourself before asking again.

Comment: that is what i am trying and without trying i can not post a comment.

Comment: You question is rather broad and it wasn't clear what you had tried. It sounds as if you're getting somewhere, so again good luck.

Comment: ok ... I could everything except getting the id of the previously selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes of course. You can put anything in a page view controller. BTW. Page view controller is just a controller for managing pages(Which are just view controllers).